# How to do Inference in TensorFlow ( EfficientDet object detection model ) with TensorRT in ml azure?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, nvidia, tensorrt

I have a workspace in ml azure where i want to observe Inference in TensorFlow (EfficientDet object detection model) with TensorRT. I am using Python 3.10, Tensorflow 2.12, TensorRT 8.6., Cuda Toolkit 11.3

Method 1: I tried model with TF TRT convert method where i took inference graph directed and and converted to TRT compatible segments by **converter.convert()** and exported (which is directory containing modified saved_model.pb and fingerprint.pb). When i load the exported model and run with test images i am getting

```
(0) UNIMPLEMENTED:  DNN library is not found.
```

Method 2: I converted model to Onnx and then Create tensorRT engine from Onnx. I was able to convert to Onnx, But when try to create engine i get

```
[06/02/2023-10:21:53] [E] [TRT] ModelImporter.cpp:777: ERROR: onnx2trt_utils.cpp:24 In function notInvalidType:
[8] Found invalid input type of UINT8
[06/02/2023-10:21:53] [E] Failed to parse onnx file
[06/02/2023-10:21:53] [I] Finished parsing network model. Parse time: 0.192559
[06/02/2023-10:21:53] [E] Parsing model failed
[06/02/2023-10:21:53] [E] Failed to create engine from model or file.
[06/02/2023-10:21:53] [E] Engine set up failed
&&&& FAILED TensorRT.trtexec [TensorRT v8601] # /usr/src/tensorrt/bin/trtexec --explicitBatch --verbose --onnx=model_m60.onnx
```